# How to parse "this is so they can..."

Tags: be, adverbials

> Ligaments connect bones to each other. This is so they can help stabilize the joints and provide structure to the skeletal frame.

[source](http://solidlifefitness.com/2014/03/16/muscles-tendons-ligaments/)

Parsing one:

"So they can help..." is predicative.

Parsing two:

"So" is predicative and there is a "that" omitted, i.e. "This is so （that）they can help stabilize...". That-clause is a
 adverbial clause of result.

Which parsing do you think is correct?

Comment: "That" is optional in this case. "So (that) they can help stabilise the joints and  provide structure to the skeletal frame" is a preposition phrase consisting of the preposition "so" + the _that_ clause as its complement. The functions is predicative: it serves as a **purpose complement**, a subtype of ascriptive predicative complement. it ascribes a purpose to the predicand.

Comment: That's modern approach. I'm not quite used to it. However, it helped me understand the structure. Thanks.

Comment: //This is so they can help stabilize the joints and provide structure to the skeletal frame.//
@BillJ, Here, doesn’t ‘so’ function as a conjunction with the meaning of ‘because’?
This is because they can help stabilize the joints and provide structure to the skeletal frame.

Comment: No: "that" is a subordinator (your conjunction). It's not possible to have two consecutive subordinators. "So" is a preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Ligaments connect bones to each other. This is* **[** *so (that) they can help*
>   *stabilize the joints and provide structure to the skeletal frame* **].**

Your parsing is not quite right. The bracketed element, "so (that) they can help stabilise the joints and provide structure to the skeletal frame" is a PP (preposition phrase) consisting of the preposition "so" as head + the *that* clause as its complement. The subordinator "that" is optional in this case.

The PP is predicative. It serves as a purpose complement, a subtype of ascriptive predicative complement: it ascribes a purpose to the predicand.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct in this case.

This is because `so` can be used to express either purpose or consequence of an action but this may lead to ambiguity. When we are emphasizing the purpose of something, we often use `so that` to emphasis a purpose but we may choose to omit the `that` part.

> I switched off the lights **so that** she can get some sleep
>
> I switched off the lights **so** she can get some sleep

However when we are talking about only the consequence (result) of an action, we must use `so` only on its own.

> It was quite hot, **so** <s>that</s> I opened all the windows